# Invert LogNorm for correct display of tick_labels of colorbar for heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, colorbar

I use (a version of) the following code to generate a heatmap with adjacent colorbar:

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

# create some dummy-data
matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[2, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2]])
# scale the data
scaled = matrix / matrix.sum(axis=1).reshape(-1,1)
```

This is what `scaled` looks like (scaling does not make a difference in this example, but it does in the intended use-case where the scaled data are used for a hierarchical linkage):

```
array([[ 0.16666667,  0.33333333,  0.5       ],
   [ 0.33333333,  0.16666667,  0.5       ],
   [ 0.5       ,  0.16666667,  0.33333333]])
```

Now I create the plot (notice the use of `LogNorm`):

```
_, ax_heatmap = plt.subplots()
heatmap = ax_heatmap.pcolor(
    scaled, edgecolors='w',
    cmap=mpl.cm.viridis_r,
    norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm())
ax_heatmap.autoscale(tight=True)
ax_heatmap.set_aspect('equal')
divider_h = make_axes_locatable(ax_heatmap)
cax = divider_h.append_axes("right", "3%", pad="1%")
plt.colorbar(heatmap, cax=cax, ticks=np.unique(scaled))
cax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(
        mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(
            lambda y, pos: ('{:.1f}'.format(y))))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

The resulting figure is as intended, but the tick-labels on the color-bar do not correspond to the intended values, which should correspond to the values found in `scaled`. I know that the function supplied to `FuncFormatter` should be used to fix this, but it's unclear which combination of transformations it should invert (or if it's the use of `LogNorm` that is inappropriate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the solution. It appears that `LogNorm` has an inverse method. By first initialising the LogNorm object with the correct vmin and vmax, its inverse can be supplied to `FuncFormatter`

```
_, ax_heatmap = plt.subplots()
norm = mpl.colors.LogNorm(vmin=scaled.min(), vmax=scaled.max())
heatmap = ax_heatmap.pcolor(
    scaled, edgecolors='w',
    cmap=mpl.cm.viridis_r,
    norm=norm)
ax_heatmap.autoscale(tight=True)
ax_heatmap.set_aspect('equal')
divider_h = make_axes_locatable(ax_heatmap)
cax = divider_h.append_axes("right", "3%", pad="1%")
plt.colorbar(heatmap, cax=cax, ticks=np.unique(scaled))
cax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(
        mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(
            lambda y, pos: ('{:.5f}'.format(norm.inverse(y)))))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I spent the last two hours trying to do exactly what your title says, with little success. Tried many things, none worked, and finally I found this elegant one-liner solution. Thanks for sharing!